# Mathematical modelling; difference equations

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, mathematical-modeling

I'm starting a course in Mathematical Modelling, and one of the sections is modelling with Difference equations.

The prerequisites for this section of the course is being able to solve basic algebra equations.
This might be a silly question but please bear with me.

Which part of High school mathematics/algebra should I concentrate on in order to be successful in this entry level mathematical modelling course?

Thanks.

Comment: I really don't get your "such as" question example.

Comment: @user8469759 I have edited my question, thanks.

Comment: I don't think "mathematical modelling" requires anything, they will probably show you some problems from biology, engineering, physics that are mathematically modelled. If your question is more like what how to solve the problem, specifically described by difference equations, just look up "calculus of differences".

Comment: @user8469759 This helps me a lot, thanks.

Comment: You might be working with matlab/scilab/python or something like that. As such linear algebra and real analysis are central. I can't say for sure, I don't know what level a course it is.We had that course in undergrad, worked with matlab and made use of mostly linear algebra.